# Where I can find "Roughness" in Properties tab > Material? (Blender 2.79)

Tags: materials

I am trying to find "Roughness" property panel in blender 2.79, but i am not able to find it. (Task is to make the reflection in the window cleaner)
Does this panel exists in blender 2.79 or not?
[image: "Roughness" in blender 2.8]

Comment: Hello :). Roughness is a part of the Principled BSDF shader. It is indeed included in Blender 2.79.

Comment: Yep, but also make sure that you are switched to Cycles renderer.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to read because we can't tell if we are looking at a reflection, a screen artifact or an actual issue with the model.